# Magento Connect Manager not updated?

Tags: magento-connect

I installed some updates for extensions manually and they work as expected. Looking at the Connect Manager still shows the old version. Why is that? 
I cleared the cache, so that can be the problem.

The same is true vor Magento version updates. If I updated from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.2, it would still show 1.9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the module is in `app/code/community(or local)/CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml` . Did you updated that as well ?

If yes **For the magento version**

The version information in the footer is pulled from app/Mage.php in the code block below. It sounds like your system has done the usual Magento Connect partial upgrade because it has not overwritten app/Mage.php.

```
/**
 * Gets the current Magento version string
 * @link http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/new-community-edition-release-process/
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function getVersion()
{
    $i = self::getVersionInfo();
    return trim("{$i['major']}.{$i['minor']}.{$i['revision']}" . ($i['patch'] != '' ? ".{$i['patch']}" : "")
                    . "-{$i['stability']}{$i['number']}", '.-');
}

/**
 * Gets the detailed Magento version information
 * @link http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/new-community-edition-release-process/
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function getVersionInfo()
{
    return array(
        'major'     => '1',
        'minor'     => '8',
        'revision'  => '0',
        'patch'     => '0',
        'stability' => '',
        'number'    => '',
    );
}
```

This usually is taken care of with a command line install using:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

As in all things Magento, you should be doing this first on a test server, and on a live production server, only after tarballing your Magento environment and doing a Magento database dump.

**For Magento connect issue**

In the downloader folder there's a file named `cache.cfg`

```
$ ls -l downloader/cache.cfg 
-rw-r--r--  1   staff  323546 May 06 17:04 downloader/cache.cfg
```

This file contains a gziped, PHP serialized array that contains all the current configuration information for you Magento Connect instance. This is where Magento Connect stores extension versions. (Extension versions are different than module versions, since a Magento extension is just a collection of files that may or may not contain a module)

You can peek at this data with the following

```
<?php
$contents       = file_get_contents('cache.cfg');
$uncompressed   = gzuncompress($contents);
$unserialized   = unserialize($uncompressed);

var_dump($unserialized['channels_by_name']['community']['packages']);
var_dump($unserialized);
```

and I believe the Magento Connect downloader saves and loads this file via the load and save methods in

```
#File: lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php
```

Comment: Yes, they were updated as well.

Comment: @Arnie Check the Updated answer